# Moving bar by pixel math calculation

Tags: math, bar-chart, pixel

I have a bargraph that has a max height of 500px. This graph itself has prices ranging from $0 to $10.5 million.

I can move the bar every 1 pixel. I am trying to come up with the math to be able to move the bargraph in $1 million interments.

I've already tried 10500000 / 500 which yields me only 21000 which is far beyond the 500px limit.

So math gurus... what should the math be for this? :o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> length of bar in dollars / length of bar in pixels = $10,500,000 / 500
>   pixels

cross-multiply to get:

> length of bar in dollars * 500 pixels = length of bar in pixels *
>   $10,500,000

divide to get "length of bar in pixels" by itself:

> length of bar in pixels = length of bar in dollars * 500 pixels /
>   $10,500,000

Now just plug in whatever money value you want to get a pixel value. For example, if you want the bar to be 3 million dollars,

> length of bar in pixels = $3,000,000 * 500 pixels / $10,500,000 = 143
>   pixels

Comment: Great! That works fine. I gave you the points because i understood your solution better than Marks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the graph to go all the way to the top, 500 pixels, it would be:

```
500 pixels / 10.5 million = 48 pixels / million
```

If you want to leave some room at the top, just increase the denominator to where you'd like the max to be, like:

```
500 pixels / 12 million = 42 pixels / million
```

(Your calc was right, it was just giving you $ / pixel, whereas I think it's more convenient here to think in pixels / million $).

Comment: Thanks for the help Mark but i understand Kevin's flow better :o)